# Output file for each key in Reducer in new MapReduce API

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am working on a single machine Cloudera Sandbox instance and I am trying to produce a output file for each Reducer output. I know that it was possible to do that in old API using `MultipleTextOutputFormat` class, however it does not work anymore. I also do not want to have drop Reduce phase.

I attach an image displaying my issue[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this one [MultipleOutputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html).

Comment: I cannot use this class, as it is from old org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce API. Current API org.apache.hadoop.mapred API does not implement write method for MultipleOutputs class.
However, I found new implementation in [new API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputs.html)

Comment: That is the other way around, org.apache.hadoop.mapred is the old API and  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce is new. For example see API for Hadoop 0.18 http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/2/hadoop-0.18/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/package-summary.html. It has mapper and not mapreduce package!!!

Comment: Thanks @alexeipab, that's a foolish mistake I made